# My footer content is not in my slidout footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I can't get my content to fit in my slideout footer. I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm not sure if I have to add it to the JavaScript.

I added the `#slideFootercontent` to the beginning to everything that I want in the footer, and it's still not working. To be clear, I want the content to slideout with the slideout footer.

I created a [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/erodriguez2385/pen/RWeVyx)

```
<footer>
    <div  class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div id="footerSlideContainer">
            <div id="footerSlideButton"></div>
            <div id="footerSlideContent" class="container ">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <br>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <h3>Latest Tweets
                                </h3>
                                <div id="example1"></div>
                                <h4>Watch me on Periscope</h4>
                                <a href="https://www.periscope.tv/Erica2385" class="periscope-on-air" data-size="large">@Erica2385</a> 
                            </div>
                            <!-- col -->
                            <div class="col-lg-4 border">
                            </div>
                            <!-- col -->
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <h3> Subscribe
                                </h3>
                                <p>Subscribe for the latest newsletters and updates</p>
                                <div id="mc_embed_signup" class="mailchimp">
                                    <form action="..." method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate form-inline" target="_blank" novalidate>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email form-control" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter email">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn btn__bottom--border mailchimp__btn" data-style="shrink" data-horizontal>        
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                                            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                                            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="..." value=""></div>
                                    </form>
                                    <span class="form_nospam">No spam</span>  
                                </div>
                                <!--End mc_embed_signup--> 
                            </div>
                            <!-- col -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- row -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- container -->
                    <hr class="container">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/alwayssunny/?fref=ts" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/alwayssunny?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://soundcloud.com/allisondanger/its-always-sunny-in-philadelphia-intro" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-2x"></i></a>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <iframe width="100" height="20" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/231337268&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: you might be able to see the issue if you clean up the formatting in your pen.

Comment: Are you refering to the 2 elements which are aside from the actual footer?

Comment: I'm still figuring codepen, but I didn't realize if you click the 'tidy' button it will clean up the code, I'll remember that for the future.

Comment: @eugensunic Everything is inside the footer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are styling `#footerSlideContainer` and `#footerSlideContent` with `position:fixed` (that prevents the content from being hidden).

Move the button (`#footerSlideButton`) outside of `#footerSlideContainer`, so it shows while that container is hidden and then style the rest appropriately. Check [your modified codepen](http://codepen.io/thierry/pen/Boqwym)

Note that I changed a few things here and there as you had bad selectors that made some rules useless and also values that created problems.